# NPM libpq and pg-native

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Im trying to install pg-native that depends on libpq.
I've installed Python and Visual C++ Libraries.
When I try npm install pg-native, i got this:

[image]

I don't know what its doing and what it wants. I can only press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and the it asks me If I want to stop Batch Jobs. I tried to leave it but nothing appens after several minutes.

What Im missing?

Comment: Looks like you haven't PostgreSQL server installed on the machine, which is a pre-requisite for `pg-native`, as it runs `pg_config` during installation which comes with the server.

Answer (score 0):

There was two problems:

1. Under Windows, you have to install: windows-build-tools who install a lot of stuffs;
2. Using nodejs 7.9 and not 8.X;